# Why do singularities define branch points?

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

Why is it that singularities of functions define branch points.
For example, $log(z)$ has a branch point at $z=0$, why then do we define a single-valued function around this point and the branch cut evolving from this point, what is it about this point which means that function fails to be single-valued around a closed path containing a singularity/branch point?

Comment: $\ln(z)$ is in general multivalued and to define it in those cases , we must choose a branch. With this choice, we can extend the domain of the function.

Comment: Your title is not accurate: Branching can only happen at essential singularities, since at poles the function just tends to $\pm\infty$ in a good manner.

For these essential singularities, one has the Great Picard theorem [enter link description here][1] .

  [1]: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Picard_theorem